# How do I turn off findbugs "Redundant nullcheck" in maven?

Tags: xml, maven, findbugs

I can't find the name of the detector that reports the "Redundant nullcheck" (RCN_REDUNDANT_NULLCHECK_OF_NONNULL_VALUE) anyone who knows which it is? Googling just gives me tons of project reports...

I get a lot of errors on it since I use JetBrains `@NotNull` annotations tool (it inserts null checks into the bytecode).

```xml
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
  <artifactId>findbugs-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.5.2</version>
  <configuration>
    <omitVisitors>???WhatIsTheDetectorsName???</omitVisitors>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: @DB5 When editing, please don't just add syntax highlighting, instead add the missing tag, in this case XML. Then the code gets automatically formatted.

Comment: @Lundin, thanks for the information, didn't know that adding a tag would give the correct formatting of code snippets contained within the question. However I thought the tags were to highlight what the question was about. This question is only about maven and findbugs, so is the XML tag relevant?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the findbugs-maven-plugin usage [documentation](http://gleclaire.github.io/findbugs-maven-plugin/usage.html) states that the `visitors`/`omitVisitors` options both specify a comma-separated list of bug detectors which should be run/not run. The bug detectors are specified by their class names, without any package qualification.

The class which checks for the redundant null check of non-null value is, as far as I can tell, [FindNullDeref](https://searchcode.com/codesearch/view/17952501/). However it does a number of other checks as well, so you would also be turning them off. Not sure if it is possible to turn off just that one check that is bothering you.

Comment: Thanks, no problem that it turns of more than just the "Redundant nullcheck" (everything it checks is already checked by IDE inspections so findbug only catches the "Redundant nullcheck"). I thought of another way to solve this issue, namely using profiles to disable the classfile processing when findbugs is run, but haven't had time to try it yet.

Comment: as stated by DB5, it is the class name. unfortunately, there seems to be no list of the class names of the bug detectors shipped with find-bugs (it is also possible to write your own detectors). so the best reference i could come up with is the FindBugs source code. right now (September 2014), the list can be found here:
https://code.google.com/p/findbugs/source/browse/findbugs/src/java/edu/umd/cs/findbugs/detect

Comment: @hoijui link shows nothing in October 2016, so I found another one: http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/api/edu/umd/cs/findbugs/detect/package-summary.html

Comment: I solved my root cause problem by forking the not-null-instrumenter I used. The new one is here: https://github.com/osundblad/intellij-annotations-instrumenter-maven-plugin the new one has a disable flag that I use during findbugs runs.

Comment: You can find most class names here: https://github.com/spotbugs/spotbugs/tree/master/spotbugs/src/main/java/edu/umd/cs/findbugs/detect