# Nonnull annotations on final field to satisfy FindBugs and IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, findbugs

I'm trying to write an immutable data class that uses @Nonnull to flag required parameters. Unfortunately whichever way I write it FindBugs flags a warning:

```java
/**
 * An error occuring during migration
 */
@Immutable
@ParametersAreNonnullByDefault
public static final class MigrationError extends MigrationResult
{
    private final String message;

    private MigrationError(String message)
    {
        this.message = message;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isSuccess()
    {
        return false;
    }

    @Nonnull
    public final String getMessage()
    {
        return message;
    }

    @Override
    public MigrationError asError()
    {
        return this;
    }
}
```

As written, this results in a Correctness warning - Null pointer dereference, Method may return null, but is declared @Nonnull. I've tried adding a null check in the constructor:

```
    private MigrationError(String message)
    {
        if (message == null)
        {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Error message cannot be null");
        }
        this.message = message;
    }
```

The warning remains however, and I now have an additional warning from Intellij that 'message == null' is always false. If I add a null check in the getter:

```
    @Nonnull
    public final String getMessage()
    {
        if (message == null)
        {
            return "";
        }
        return message;
    }
```

I get the same warning from IntelliJ and FindBugs gives me a new warning: Dodgy code: Redundant comparison to null: Redundant nullcheck of value known to be non-null. I get the same FindBugs warning if I remove the explicit null check and add `@Nonnull` to the `message` field.

I can suppress the warnings, but I'd like to know what FindBugs expects. Is there is some pattern for declaring an immutable field NonNull? Does it matter that it is a static nested class within its parent class?

Comment: FindBugs uses a complex set of heuristics, making it hard to diagnose its false positives and false negatives.  As a point of comparison, the [Checker Framework](http://checkerframework.org/)'s [Nullness Checker](http://types.cs.washington.edu/checker-framework/current/checker-framework-manual.html#nullness-checker) processes this code without issuing any false positive warnings.  You don't need to modify your annotations, because the Checker Framework can [read FindBugs annotations](http://types.cs.washington.edu/checker-framework/current/checker-framework-manual.html#nullness-related-work).

Comment: Try hoisting `message` into local var and perform the null check and return against the local var.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @jmehrens, unfortunately that results in a redundant null check warning. Might just chalk it up to complex heuristics and move on.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19213158/how-do-i-turn-off-findbugs-redundant-nullcheck-in-maven